# Deserialize JSON with dynamic properties with JSON.NET in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I've got a JSON that, for example, looks like

```
{"historymatch":
   {
    "id":[1581402],
    "mid":[166],
    "aid":[5621],
    "bid":[18548],
    "date":["24/05/16"],
    "liveA":[3],
    "liveB":[1],
    "redA":[0],
    "redB":[0],
    "bc":["3-0"],
    "ng":[0],
    "rq":["-1.5"],
    "rql":[0],
    "worl":[0],
    "oworl":[0]},
    "match":
    {
        "166":
        {
           "n":"INT CF",
           "c":"5691D8"
        }
    },
    "team":
    {
       "5621":"Melbourne Knights",
       "18548":"Dandenong City SC"
    },
    "note":{}
}
```

As you can see there are dynamic properties and field in match and in team.
I tried to reflect this in my c# classes

```
class History<T> where T : new()
{
    public HistoryMatch<T> HistoryMatch { get; set; }
}
class HistoryMatch<T> where T: new()
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public IList<long> MatchId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("mid")]
    public IList<long> LeagueId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("aid")]
    public IList<long> TeamAId { get; set; }


 [JsonProperty("bid")]
    public IList<long> TeamBId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public IList<string> MatchDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("liveA")]
    public IList<long> TeamAScore { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("liveB")]
    public IList<long> TeamBScore { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("redA")]
    public IList<long> TeamARedCard { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("redB")]
    public IList<long> TeamBRedCard { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("bc")]
    public IList<string> HalfTimeScore { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ng")]
    public IList<long> Ng { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("rq")]
    public IList<string> Rq { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("rql")]
    public IList<long> Rql { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("worl")]
    public IList<long> Worl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("oworl")]
    public List<long> Oworl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("match")]
    public Dictionary<string,T> Match { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("team")]
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("note")]
    public Note Note { get; set; }
}

class Match
{
    [JsonProperty("n")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("c")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

class Team
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }
}

class Note
{

}
```

Then I deserialize it the following way

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<History<Match>>(responseText);
```

It is deserialized without an error but the Attributes `Match` and `Team` of the class `HistoryMatch` are `null` afterwards. 
I've taken several attemps now but it seems that I'm missing something essential here. 
Could someone please give me an advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Json `Team`, `Match` and `Notes` are not parts of the `HistoryMatch`, but parts of the `History`. Define your `History` class this way, i did it an i have deserialized your team and match values.

```
class History<T> where T : new()
{
    public HistoryMatch<T> HistoryMatch { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("match")]
    public Dictionary<string, T> Match { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("team")]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Team { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("note")]
    public Note Note { get; set; }
}
```

And you don't nede to define `Team` as separate class, as i see it in your json it just a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Comment: You are right! Damn, I got confused by the open and closen brackets. Thank you for your help